# Gurobi generates wrong solutions when dealing with small numbers

Tags: python, binary, gurobi

I am using Gurobi on Python interface, to solve a mathematical programming model, for a class of single machine scheduling problem, that contains both Binary and Continuous variables. In some cases, when dealing with small numbers, the solution generated by Gurobi is not valid.

The thing that Gurobi does that makes the solution valid from its perspective is that some Binary variables have values like 0.9999912 or 0.000000002. Doing that, the model generates a solution in which two jobs occupy the machine at the same time, that is invalid. Although the amount of the time that the two jobs overlap is very small (for example 0.004 time unit), it makes the solution incorrect.

I would like to know if I can modify the parameters in a way that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please look below link, Modelling and Algorithms section, Question 26. You will find answer. http://www.gurobi.com/support/faqs#modeling-and-algorithms